# Harmon.ie options - License tab missing

Tags: harmon.ie

How to find out the harmon.ie edition and license expiration date if the License tab is missing? And why is it missing in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not see the license tab it means you are running the Free edition, hence no expiration date.The only license message you can get with the free edition is about exceeding the 15 installations per organization.
Did you purchase harmon.ie Enterprise edition?

---- Jean

Comment: Hi Jean, thank you for your reply. That's the whole point - it suppose to be Enterprise, but I can't verify it. Previous installation included 'Go Enterprise' button in harmon.ie pane in Outlook. Now my manager states that our company went for 'Enterprise' and, after re-installing it, 'Go Enterprise' button is not visible anymore. Still, I need to be sure about it.

Comment: Hi Where did you get the Enterprise version from? Are you customer? Please disclose your company name.

Comment: Hi, Enterprise/Free is written in the About dialog…